# Facebook fb:likebox width went wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I had a `fb:likebox` that had proper width since last year. However recently suddenly the width of the box went wrong, it became much wider than it was before.

In the HTML source I still see the `width="185"` setting being there, but it has no effect.

The site can be seen here: http://tinyurl.com/m932dlq

Do you have any idea what might have changed? Did Facebook change something? I haven't found any other similar complaints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has broken it, but you can revert it by a bit of CSS:

```
.fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box iframe {
    width: 185px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook changed the fan box. The minimum width is now 292px. Here's the link for [FB Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)